# "Double Group By" in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

As I was learning SQL statements I encountered one example (regarding the demo [SCOTT](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SCOTT) database), I have no idea how to solve.

> In which department(s) are all salgrades present?

My most promising approach is to **group all salgrades and departments** in the joined tables **emp**, **dept** and **salgrade**:

```
SELECT s.grade AS "Salgrade",
       d.dname AS "Department ID"
FROM emp e INNER JOIN dept d ON(e.deptno = d.deptno)
     INNER JOIN salgrade s ON(e.sal BETWEEN s.losal AND s.hisal)
GROUP BY d.dname, s.grade
```

Executing this gives me the following results:

[image: results]

If I could group this another time by department, *COUNT(*)* could give me the **number of different salgrades per department**. Then I could compare this number (with *HAVING*) to the following subselect:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM salgrade)
```

Is there any possibility to group a table which already contains
   *GROUP BY*?
Is there another (better) approach I could use?

---

I am using an apex-oracle-server with *"Application Express 4.2.4.00.07"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an even easier solution now:

```
SELECT d.dname
FROM emp e  INNER JOIN dept d ON(e.deptno = d.deptno)
            INNER JOIN salgrade s ON(e.sal BETWEEN s.losal AND s.hisal)
GROUP BY d.dname
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.grade) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM salgrade);
```

Comment: Good Attempt! Nice work! Just that I was stunned with a -15 :(

Answer (score 1):

Minor change from your version, by removing the grouping inside, and this version, first generates, `salgrade` and `department` of all employees, and then doing a grouping outside, counting distinct salary grades.

```
SELECT Department_ID
FROM
(
 SELECT s.grade AS Salgrade,
        d.dname AS Department_ID
 FROM emp e 
  INNER JOIN dept d ON(e.deptno = d.deptno)
  INNER JOIN salgrade s ON(e.sal BETWEEN s.losal AND s.hisal)
 )
GROUP BY Department_ID
HAVING COUNT(distinct Salgrade) = ( SELECT count(1) FROM salgrade);
```

Comment: I understand this solution and it seems fine to me, but I keep getting: "ORA-00904: "SALGRADE": invalid identifier" The COUNT(distinct Salgrade) doesn't seem to work...

Comment: try now please, with my editted one, it should work!

Answer (score 0):

Simple way would be - if performance is not a problem.

```
SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT [Salgrade]) AS [COUNT]
,[Department ID]
FROM (SELECT s.grade AS "Salgrade",
       d.dname AS "Department ID"
FROM emp e INNER JOIN dept d ON(e.deptno = d.deptno)
     INNER JOIN salgrade s ON(e.sal BETWEEN s.losal AND s.hisal)
GROUP BY d.dname, s.grade) DEPT_SALE
GROUP BY [Department ID]
```

There could be better solutions though if we know more of your base tables - `emp` & `salegrade`

Comment: thanks for your quick answer! you can find more information about the base tables here: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SCOTT

Comment: And you requirement is only to get the distinct count of salesgrade by department ?

Comment: I need to get all departments where all (different) salgrades are present. If there are 5 grades, all have to be at least once in the department.

Comment: That is invalid SQL for Oracle (and non-standard SQL as well)